# Error in NextMethod(.Generic) : cannot assign 'tsp' to zero-length vector in R

Tags: r, generics

Here my dataset( it is big, so i provide  little part)

```
 timeseries=structure(list(date = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("01.01.2018", 
    "02.01.2018", "03.01.2018"), class = "factor"), racket = c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L), shuttlecock = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
    10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 5L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 10L), price = c(14.88, 14.88, 14.88, 
    14.88, 14.88, 14.88, 14.88, 14.88, 14.88, 14.88, 12.9, 12.9, 
    12.9, 12.9, 12.9, 12.9, 12.9, 12.9, 12.9, 12.9, 12.9, 12.9, 12.9, 
    14.88, 17.85, 17.85, 14.88, 14.88, 17.85, 14.88, 17.85, 17.85, 
    14.88, 14.88, 14.88, 14.88, 14.88, 14.88, 14.88, 14.88, 14.88, 
    14.88, 14.88, 14.88, 14.88, 14.88, 14.88, 14.88, 14.88, 14.88, 
    14.88, 14.88, 12.9, 12.9, 12.9, 12.9, 12.9, 12.9, 12.9, 12.9, 
    12.9, 12.9, 17.85, 14.88, 14.88, 14.88, 14.88, 17.85, 14.88, 
    14.88, 14.88, 14.88, 17.85, 14.88, 14.88, 14.88, 14.88, 14.88, 
    14.88, 14.88, 14.88, 14.88, 14.88, 14.88, 14.88, 12.9)), .Names = c("date", 
    "racket", "shuttlecock", "price"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -86L))
```

and my script

```
#split analysis on groups
group_list <- split(timeseries, list(timeseries$racket, timeseries$shuttlecock))
group_list <- group_list[sapply(group_list, function(x) nrow(x) != 0)]


library("lubridate")
#create forecast
fun_msts <- function(timeseries){
  msts(timeseries$price, seasonal.periods = c(7,365.25), start = decimal_date(as.Date("2018-01-01")))
}

library("forecast")
msts_list <- lapply(group_list, fun_msts)
#sp_list <- lapply(msts_list, fun_sp)


listed_arima <- lapply(msts_list,function(x) auto.arima(x,allowmean = FALSE)) 

#Now the forecast for each arima:
listed_forecast <- lapply(listed_arima,function(x) forecast(x,5) )
listed_forecast


lapply(listed_arima, fitted)

#For the same reason you may also use AIC Metrix
listed_arima <- lapply(listed_ts, auto.arima)
```

Then i want get  MAPE metrics i use MLmetrics library , cause  it is more convenient

```
library("MLmetrics")

out <- mapply(MAPE, lapply(listed_arima, fitted), split(timeseries$price, group_list)); names(out) <- names(split(timeseries$price, group_list))
out
```

and after i get the error

> Error in NextMethod(.Generic) : cannot assign 'tsp' to zero-length
>   vector

Why this error occurs , i need get MAPE for each group.
How to do correct?

Comment: do you get the same error from the `lapply(listed_arima, fitted)` alone?

Comment: @jenesaisquoi, no, i get values.

Comment: oh I'm sorry I completely missed that was already in your example, I was only asking since `fitted` is a generic method, although it doesn't appear `listed_ts` is anywhere - I assume it is the same as `listed_arima`

Comment: you;re problem appears to be in `split(timeseries$price, group_list)` which just returns a bunch empty entries, you might be better off using `aggregate` or perhaps the more intuitive `group_by` from `dplyr` or `data.table`

Comment: Can you show me, how to do it in answer, that i accept it?

Comment: are you just trying to use the unique prices corresponding to each combination of (racket, shuttlecock)?

Comment: @jenesaisquoi, yes it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears your problem is arising from `split(timeseries$price, group_list)`, which returns a bunch of empty elements (since `group_list` isn't matching prices).

A simple fix to use the unique price for each grouping of (racket, shuttlecock) could be the following,

```
mapply(MAPE, lapply(listed_arima, fitted), 
    sapply(group_list, function(g) unique(g$price)))

 1.2  1.5 0.10 
   1    1    1
```

You may additionally be interested in the `setNames` to save the additional `names<-` call or something like

```
with(list(nms = names(group_list)), ... ; names(...) <- nms)
```

if the value will be used repeatedly but you would rather just compute it once.

Alternative packages that are often more efficient for these types of grouping operations, and sometimes more intuitive are `dplyr::group_by` or `data.table` (its learning curve is steaper IMHO, but it is likely more efficient -- at least it used to be when I used R more often).